# Pentaho JPivot gives Resultset Overflow Occured

Tags: java, mysql, overflow, pentaho

I am using JPivot that ships with Pentaho 3.8.0.stable.45256.
Whenever I try to drill down in a JPivot report it gives me `Resultset Overflow Occurred`. When I second time click on the `+` sign and drill down it works. I googled for this and found that it comes because of the settings in `mondrian.properties`. Following are the settings that I did as per instructions in one of the Pentaho forum:

```
mondrian.result.limit=0
mondrian.olap.case.sensitive=false
mondrian.native.crossjoin.enable=false
mondrian.native.ExpandNonNative=false
```

All of the above setting are placed in

`pentaho-solutions/system/mondrian/mondrian.properties`

And did restarted the Pentaho. But the error still persist. It looks like either these chages are not taking effect or there is some issue with the Query that is generated by JPivot.

I enabled the log4j to verify the query and looked into the logs when error occurred. There is no error logged in the log file nor even the query generated when I drill down. It only shows the MDX query. Other reports that are running good, I see SQL queries logged for them.  If this error is due to the sql query then it should not even run second time. But it does.

What could be the issue? can it be because of Java heap Memory getting Overflowed?

1. JPivot settings somewhere that I am missing?
2. MySQL query not getting generated correctly? If yes then how do I find the query, as it is not in logs.
3. Java Heap Memory?

FYI:

1. RAM: 16GB
2. There are more than 45 million records in the table which are aggregated.
3. The CATALINA_OPTs settings are:

   `-d64 -server -Xms2048m -Xmx6144m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+UseLargePages -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution to my problem.

I have increased the session and query time out in Pentaho as well as increased the timeout of my tomcat and Apache (Serve as a proxy server) and that helped. It is working now and I have also made one of the above parameter to true as shown here:

```
mondrian.native.crossjoin.enable=true
```